# Oracle Materialized Vies Time of Refresh

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have 36 oracle materialized views.  I want to stager out at what time they get refreshed.

The problem is no mater what I try, it always ends up at 3 minutes after the hour.
With the select below I would get 45 minutes after midnight of the next day:
select TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 3/96 from dual;
16-MAR-18 00:45:00

But if I put that into an alter command:
 ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_MV
   REFRESH COMPLETE
   START WITH TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) +  3/96
   NEXT SYSDATE+1;

It sets the next run as 3 minutes after midnight:
03/16/2018 00:03:00

I can change the hour of the refresh, but seems for some reason not to allow me to set the minutes after the hour.

Any suggestions??

Comment: You should go for [Scheduler Jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034), there you can schedule the task much more precise.

Comment: Problem with Jobs (not Scheduler Jobs) is the "next time" is evaluated when the current jobs has been finished. For example if you have a daily job (by `SYSDATE+1`) running for 10 Minutes then the execution time is shifted every day by 10 Minutes.

Comment: Hi Wernfried, thanks for the input, but that does not answer the question.  Please take a look again at my question and the examples I gave.  For the information you did give, it does not seem to be working that way.  If it was I would get some shifting of the start times everyday, the start times are staying at 3 minute after the hour and that is my problem, I do not want all the refreshes starting at the same time.